# What is the right way to handle a flag that has "aged away"

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

Recently, I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150546/the-best-overloaded-method-match-xxx-has-some-invalid-arguments) which had clearly had been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543334/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-xxx-has-some-invalid-arguments).

At first, I incorrectly created a new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29150743/700390) suggesting that the user should look at the other question.  Some other user pointed out that it would be better to flag the question as a duplicate, which I did.

Some time later, my answer was deleted by moderator, presumably because it only contained a link to the other question (which is fine, no complaints there).

However, nobody ever reviewed the duplicate flag and it is now "aged away" - now as a result, we have a question with no answers and no reference to the duplicate.  I cannot re-flag the question, and chances of someone else coming along to do so is probably low given that the question is now several weeks old and not highly rated.

What is the correct approach to getting this resolved?  Do I create a moderator attention flag (or will this just get the moderators more annoyed at me), is there some other suggested approach, or do I just leave it be and try to feel good about doing the best I could to fix the problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, since you posted it here I went ahead and closed it. But that's a lot of work for you to go through, so in the future just re-flag it: the question will go up for review again, and perhaps catch a bit more attention this time.

Note that there's a 14-day waiting period for re-raising aged flags, so you might have to wait a little bit.

Comment: Many thanks, I did not realize that I would be able to re-flag it after 14 days.  I'll be sure to do that next time instead of making such a fuss about it!

Comment: No worries, perhaps your question here will go on to benefit others.

Comment: For most of my "Aged away" flags, I can't re-flag after they 14-day waiting period. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629525/java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-zip-createprocess-error-2-the-system) is just one of several questions I want to re-flag. What should I do?