# Is there a problem with the review process?

Tags: discussion

Recently I stumbled over some off-topic questions simply asking for a tool (or the best tool) for some tasks. At least two of those (non-)questions where first posts from new users. When I flagged the questions, the flags aged away.

Shouldn't there be a review in the first place to prevent bad quality first posts from getting posted? And why do so many flags age away? For me it looks like there is some general problem in the quality-assuring processes if such things happen—too little care in reviews? Too less moderators? Am I wrong?

The two questions mentioned are:
[What are ALM/DevOps vendors originating from Germany (by HQ)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500081/what-are-alm-devops-vendors-originating-from-germany-by-hq) and [Test case repository for BDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965669/test-case-repository-for-bdd).

Comment: But .. you didn't down vote, right? Those questions are not useful and that is a valid down vote reason. Down votes don't expire and in the end the [roomba](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) will pick them up ...

Answer (score 5):

Community moderation is not perfect, no. The close-vote review queue is notoriously full and behind, sometimes only inexperienced or robo-reviewers have seen the post in the 'first post' or 'low quality' review queues, sometimes people that have enough reputation to bypass low-quality reviews post low-quality questions anyway. So what can happen, is that posts with a low view count don't gather enough votes in time to be closed.

That's not necessarily a problem, however. As they are posts with a low view count (45 views in 10 days, 127 views in 10 months), not many people actually notice these. Many such questions are [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) too.

If those posts manage to remain on the site and actually become a problem in the future (higher view counts, being used to justify other questions being open), the increased attention will lead to them being dealt with soon enough. You brought attention to these two posts now, so I closed them.

Answer (score 1):

SO is very big site to manage and some review questions are overlooked as you know at least 10k close vote question wait for review even if your flag is aged don't worry you can reflag it after 14 days.

References

- [What is the right way to handle a flag that has "aged away"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289728/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-a-flag-that-has-aged-away)

Comment: So maybe there is a systemic problem if the review queues are that full? And if more questions get reflaged, the review-queues won't get smaller...

Comment: Not a systematic problem but there are less close vote privilege holder user than flag privilege user.

Comment: On low traffic tags you can consider to leave a cv-pls in [SOCVR](http://socvr.org/tour)