# Flags aging away

Tags: discussion, support, flags

This is a follow up question to this question:

[What is the right way to handle a flag that has "aged away"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289728/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-a-flag-that-has-aged-away)

Why when a flag ages away, it can not be raised again? That flag was overlooked and should be able to be raised again.

A user should be able to re flag the same flag until some sort of answer was received for this flag, if it was either helpful, rejected or disputed. If it had simply aged away, then the user should be able to reflag it so the flag's reviewer can decide on an action if they missed the flag in the first time.

The answer to the above question said you can re flag in 14 days, but its simply not true. For example I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978019/eclipse-does-not-open) for closure on march 23rd, 14:09 but shows as aged away but I can't re-raise it.

Comment: It was not overlooked, maybe nobody felt enough reason to follow your flag.

Comment: Anyway, if you want an extra pair of eyes on a post that you plan to flag, feel free to drop in the SOCVR chat room. The regulars can offer advice what the best call to action, if any, is and when warranted help out with close or delete votes. VLQ and NAA flags are kind of pointless as once such flag is raised it ends in the review queue anyway.

Comment: It WAS overlooked. If nobody thought an action is justified, then the flag would have been disputed, not aging away.

Comment: Skipping is an option in the queue. But if you make it more concrete, what flag did you raise on which post?

Comment: There were many of them and that's the problem.. there are so many flags people skip and then it can not be flagged again. If a user could re flag it then other reviewers could decide something should be done or at least disputed. No flag should even get an "aged away" and then be simply forgotten.

Comment: by the way i've edited the question to explain why its not a duplicate

Comment: I still don't understand and you seem to refuse to provide that info, if the flags were flags for closure or not.

Comment: Yeah. What else can you flag about if not for closure? And I didn't refuse anything.. I just can't link here all the 99 questions that I've flagged that were aged away..

Comment: Well, you can flag for Not An Answer, Spam, Rude/Abusive, VLQ, comment flag, custom mod flag and close. So my question is not that strange in my opinion ...

Comment: So you have flagged a question for closure more then 2 weeks ago, which flag has aged away and you can't re-flag that question again, right? I just need one example out of your 99 cases to see if you might have found a bug. because bugs do happen now and then, specially if it involves scripts that need to run.

Comment: Relevant background on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)

Comment: ok I just checked it again to see Im not mistaken and it seems that only the question I did check in the first place which did not allow me to re flag is actually the only one with that situation.. This is the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978019/eclipse-does-not-open

Comment: That question did had a review in the cvq based on the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42978019/timeline) but was invalidated for some reason. Did you flag it on Mar, 23rd ?

Comment: Yeah march 23rd, 14:09

Comment: Ok, I re-opened this but here is what I think will be the answer for your example flag: the close review task was invalidated on Apr, 8th. That caused the Aged away event. Between that date and now only 8 days passed, so it would need another 4 days before you can re-flag this specific question. That said: it can use some better clarification how to diagnose aged away flags and the (im)possibility to re-flag.

Comment: @rene we need no MCVE on meta :P

Comment: There are normally *several thousand* (currently 8,566) questions in the close-vote (CV) review queue. 5 people must CV a question to close it. That's 42,830 votes, just to clear the current queue. Each user with the CV privilege has 50 CV/day, that's 857 user-days just to clear the queue. It doesn't begin to consider the huge volume of closable questions which are added to the site every day. The reality is that a huge number of questions that should be closed, just don't get closed due to the amount of effort required to do so overwhelming the volunteers who spend time voting to close.

Comment: No-one cares about close flags/votes. Just wait until you have 3k reputation and then you can start wasting your daily allowance of close votes instead of flags.

Comment: Yeah Makyen now that I know you CAN actually reflag after 14 days as soon as the flag gets aged then its ok

Comment: either YonatanNir or @rene could add this as an answer

Comment: @eis I have tried to poke a mod. If they respond I'll write an answer. if not they might have suspended me in the mean time for unauthorized poking of mods.

Comment: added the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you CAN actually re raise a flag after 14 days it was aged away.

The flag for the question I brought as an example was invalidated for some reason and was later reopened per my request.

We need to remember that there is a huge number of flags to review by those who have 3k+ reputation, and with 5 votes to close a question, a flag can age away quite often.

That being said, it can use some better clarification how to diagnose aged away flags and the (im)possibility to re-flag.